# Facebook Marketing API, retrieving ad hourly_stats_aggregated_by_advertiser_time_zone analytics in the past

Tags: facebook, analytics, ads-api

I'm build historical database for facebook adaccount analytics.

In our query, we set breakdown to 'hourly_stats_aggregated_by_advertiser_time_zone' and aggregate insights later.

Problem is some ads in the past seem not support this breakdown and return empty so i just want to know from which time in the past this breakdown can be applied?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since 12th of April 2016 the v2.6 of the Facebook Marketing API supports 'hourly_stats_aggregated_by_advertiser_time_zone' breakdowns

Visit:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog?locale=us_EN
for further information